# initialization of bibtex package

Tags: use-package, bibtex

When i ran the following code in just started emacs

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (insert "@article{aaaa,
    author =     {AAA},
    title =  {BBBB}
    }")
  (bibtex-mode)
  (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title"))
```

I get the following error:

```
  Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
    looking-at(nil)
    bibtex-valid-entry(t)
    bibtex-end-of-entry()
    bibtex-text-in-field("title" t)
    bibtex-autokey-get-field("title")
    (progn (insert "@article{aaaa,\n    author =     {AAA},\n    title =  {BBBB}\n    }") (bibtex-mode) (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title"))
    (unwind-protect (progn (insert "@article{aaaa,\n    author =     {AAA},\n    title =  {BBBB}\n    }") (bibtex-mode) (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title")) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))
    (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert "@article{aaaa,\n    author =     {AAA},\n    title =  {BBBB}\n    }") (bibtex-mode) (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title")) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))
    (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert "@article{aaaa,\n    author =     {AAA},\n    title =  {BBBB}\n    }")       (bibtex-mode) (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title")) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))))
    eval((let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert "@article{aaaa,\n    author =     {AAA},\n    title =  {BBBB}\n    }") (bibtex-mode) (bibtex-autokey-get-field "title")) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer))))) nil)
    elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
    eval-last-sexp(t)
    eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
    funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
    call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
    command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
```

After i open any bibtex file the above code works as expected. (I get "BBBB")

If it is important i initialize the bibtex with the following:

```
  (use-package bibtex
    :mode ("\\.bib" . bibtex-mode)
    )
```

Could you help me to find the problem

Comment: Please explain *how* it "doesn't work" and what you do exactly to try and run that code (and not just "similar" code).  Also I don't understand what your `use-package` call is for: Emacs's default config will already use `bibtex-mode` for files with the `.bib` extension.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, i rewrote the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in bibtex.el which only initializes some of its global vars after opening a file.  Please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

While waiting for an actual fix, you can use the following workaround: add a call of the form `(bibtex-set-dialect)` some time after calling `bibtex-mode`.

Comment: You have to give some value as ```"biblatex"```. For example: ```(bibtex-set-dialect "biblatex")```